# Flutter App working on emulator but On Real device cant tap

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have A Project. After i implement cubit to my project on real phone i cant tap anywhere. Like its frozen. But on emulator its works without a problem. When i dont use cubit its works. What is wrong with it ? Thanks for responses.

---

Code :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Inter', backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFBF8FF)),
      home: DismissKeyboard(child: AuthController()),
    );
  }
}

class AuthController extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthController({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AuthController> createState() => _AuthControllerState();
}

class _AuthControllerState extends State<AuthController> {
  _AuthControllerState();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthCubit>(
      create: (context) => AuthCubit(repository: AuthService()),
      child: BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthUnAuthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen();
          } else if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

I Can see LoginScreen with that code. But cant click anywhere on real phone.

---

Cubit:

```
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  AuthCubit({required this.repository}) : super(AuthLoaded()) {
    checkToken();
  }

  final AuthService repository;

  void checkToken() async {
    final token = await UserSecureStorage.getField("token");
    if (token == null)
      emit(AuthUnAuthenticated());
    else
      emit(AuthAuthenticated());
  }
```

Comment: Share the code of the page that you can't touch on the phone. I assume that is the LoginPage()

Comment: change the device and try once.